# grep a rar in cygwin

Tags: linux, shell, cygwin

I want to do grep texts files inside a rar without extracting the rar file to disk, I tried a couple of combinations with pipes however it didnt work i tried for example

> unrar e myrar.rar | grep mysearchedline

however it actually opened it to disk, I don't want to open it to disk, I don't have enough space for it to be opened (its real big with real big logs).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `p` instead of `e`, and don't forget to specify the name of the file you want to grep through.

Comment: Thank you very much this indeed works. I didn't need to specify the file because i'm looking for a string in all text files inside a rar (I don't know in which file it is).